# Javascript New Input Field With Button and html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have created this part of code. Whenever a button is pushed a new input forum field is being added in the form. How can I add text and a number beside the field each time (starting from 3)?
For example: Option 1: the input type field
             Option 2: the input type field
             Option 3: the input type field
and so on

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript"> function add() {
//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", 'text');
element.setAttribute("value", '');
element.setAttribute("name", 'text[]');


var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
//Append the element in page (in span).
foo.appendChild(element);

}
</SCRIPT>
```

The above part of code is being used by the following (just for a reference):

```
<b>Option 1:</b> <input type="text" name="text[]" /><br />
<b>Option 2:</b> <input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add()"/>
<span id="fooBar"></span>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var temp = 3;

function add() {
var element = document.createElement("input");
var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "Option "+temp;
//Assign different attributes to the element.
 element.setAttribute("type", 'text');
 element.setAttribute("value", '');
 element.setAttribute("name", 'text[]');


 var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

  foo.appendChild(span);
  foo.appendChild(element);

temp++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var optionCount = 3;

 function add() {
   //Create an input type dynamically.
   var element = document.createElement("input");
   var label = document.createElement("label");
   label.innerHTML = "Option " + optionCount++ +":"
     //Assign different attributes to the element.
   element.setAttribute("type", 'text');
   element.setAttribute("value", '');
   element.setAttribute("name", 'text[]');


   var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
   //Append the element in page (in span).
   foo.appendChild(label);
   foo.appendChild(element);

 }
```

```html
<b>Option 1:</b> 
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<br />
<b>Option 2:</b> 
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add()" />
<span id="fooBar"></span>
```